# xslt moving up child attribute to parent and remove first linie.

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, move

Input:

```
<Conductor Tag="A111K" Type="Normal" Length="7481" Length_Status="Real" Gauge="0.5" Wire_Type="08NtyH" Class="" Segregation="2A" TemperatureZone="20" Net="163K" Description="" Material="Undefined" MaterialType="Copper" ExternalDiameter="8.8" ProvidedWithEquipment="No" Color="BU" TagType="Standard" WireOrder="0" SourceType="Automatic" ManualAssignation="No" Resistivity="0" XDirectionLength="5497">
                        <UserAttribute AttributeName="NeoNetTAG" AttributeValue="blabla_018" />
                        <UserAttribute AttributeName="NeoWireTAG" AttributeValue="xxxxxxx_02" />
                        <MFConductorExtremityFrom/>
    </Conductor>
```

output

```
<Conductor AttributeValue="xxxxxxx_02" Tag="A111K" Type="Normal" Length="7481" Length_Status="Real" Gauge="0.5" Wire_Type="08NtyH" Class="" Segregation="2A" TemperatureZone="20" Net="163K" Description="" Material="Undefined" MaterialType="Copper" ExternalDiameter="8.8" ProvidedWithEquipment="No" Color="BU" TagType="Standard" WireOrder="0" SourceType="Automatic" ManualAssignation="No" Resistivity="0" XDirectionLength="5497">
                    <MFConductorExtremityFrom/>
</Conductor>
```

I try: XSLT but only remove both:(

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Conductor">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!--
      Apply the attributes of the current node and the attributes of all
      following siblings (in this case, <address> and <phone>)
      -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | following-sibling::*/@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Drop the <address> and <phone> elements -->
  <xsl:template match="AttributeValue"/>

  <!--
  Identity transform: copy attributes and elements from input document to output
  document as is
  -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've been at this a while now - have got the XSLT working mostly, removed unwanted nodes and attributes, but there's one part of it that is throwing me.
Help me:(

Comment: Can you explain the logic in more detail. It looks like you are copying the `AttributeValue` attribute from a child element, but why not `AttributeName`? Also, why are the child elements `UserAttribute` removed, but not `MFConductorExtremityFrom`? Thanks

Comment: thank you for your interest, the goal of this xslt is: remove: <UserAttribute AttributeName="NeoNetTAG" AttributeValue="blabla_018" /> and move data from <UserAttribute AttributeName="NeoWireTAG" AttributeValue="xxxxxxx_02" />  but only AttributeValue="xxxxxxx_02" to  <Conductor. MFConductorExtremityFrom have more attributs and must remain.

Answer (score 0):

I think the expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="@*|UserAttribute[@AttributeName='NeoWireTAG']/@AttributeValue"/>
```

Or maybe this, as I am not sure of your exact logic....

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|UserAttribute[last()]/@AttributeValue"/>
```

You also need a template to then remove the `UserAttribute` nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="UserAttribute"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Conductor">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|UserAttribute[last()]/@AttributeValue"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="UserAttribute"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```